# Not receive notification with azure notification hub when using tag

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I'm new to this. The example of android is from 
[GetStartedFirebase](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/Android/GetStartedFirebase)

Below are the steps:

1) I install the android to my phone

2) I followed this example to create my web api
https//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-gcm-android-push-to-user-google-notification

3) i comment out the AuthenticationTestHandler class

4)i call the below code from fiddle

The DeviceRegistration object

```
{
  "Platform": "gcm",
  "Handle": "regid i get from android",
  "Tags": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ]
}
```

// This creates or updates a registration (with provided channelURI) at the specified id

```
      public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(string id, DeviceRegistration deviceUpdate)
    {
        RegistrationDescription registration = null;
        switch (deviceUpdate.Platform)
        {
            case "mpns":
                registration = new MpnsRegistrationDescription(deviceUpdate.Handle);
                break;
            case "wns":
                registration = new WindowsRegistrationDescription(deviceUpdate.Handle);
                break;
            case "apns":
                registration = new AppleRegistrationDescription(deviceUpdate.Handle);
                break;
            case "gcm":
                registration = new GcmRegistrationDescription(deviceUpdate.Handle);
                break;
            default:
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        registration.RegistrationId = id;

        var username = "test";

        string[] userTag = new string[1];
        userTag[0] = "username:" + username;
        registration.Tags = new HashSet<string>(userTag);
        try
        {
            await hub.CreateOrUpdateRegistrationAsync(registration);
        }
        catch (MessagingException e)
        {
            ReturnGoneIfHubResponseIsGone(e);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

5)  Then i call to send the push notification

http://localhost:4486/api/Notifications?pns=gcm&to_tag=test

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string pns, [FromBody]string message, string to_tag)
{

    var user = "test";
    message = "msg";
    string[] userTag = new string[1];
    userTag[0] = "username:" + to_tag;     

    Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationOutcome outcome = null;
    HttpStatusCode ret = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

    switch (pns.ToLower())
    {
        case "wns":
            // Windows 8.1 / Windows Phone 8.1
            var toast = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01""><text id=""1"">" +
                        "From " + user + ": " + message + "</text></binding></visual></toast>";
            outcome = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(toast, userTag);
            break;
        case "apns":
            // iOS
            var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + "From " + user + ": " + message + "\"}}";
            outcome = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alert, userTag);
            break;
        case "gcm":
            // Android
            var notif = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"" + "From " + user + ": " + message + "\"}}";
            outcome = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notif, userTag);
            break;
    }

    if (outcome != null)
    {
        if (!((outcome.State == Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationOutcomeState.Abandoned) ||
            (outcome.State == Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationOutcomeState.Unknown)))
        {
            ret = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(ret);
}
```

No error returned but i do not receive any notification.

I try to remove usertag as below:

```
outcome = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notif);
```

I am able to receive the notification.

Why the tag doesn't work ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you go through [Diagnosis guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer) and update the question with what you've learned?

Answer (score 2):

```
var allRegistrations = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0);
```

Check your tag in `allRegistrations`. If it is there then it should work.

You can check test notification from http://pushtry.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused - JSON from Fiddler shows that the registration has "1" and "2" tags, but everywhere in the code you are using "username:test" tag. Can you get this registration from the hub and make sure that it has correct tags?
You can use `GetRegistrationAsync<TRegistrationDescription>(String)` [1], `GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(String, Int32)` [2] or `GetAllRegistrationsAsync(Int32)` [3] methods to get the registration.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient#Microsoft_Azure_NotificationHubs_NotificationHubClient_GetRegistrationAsync__1_System_String_

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient#Microsoft_Azure_NotificationHubs_NotificationHubClient_GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync_System_String_System_Int32_

[3] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient#Microsoft_Azure_NotificationHubs_NotificationHubClient_GetAllRegistrationsAsync_System_Int32_

Comment: Initially i did include the "1" and "2" tags from parameter, but it doesnt work so i just try to use only one tag from registration and ignore those tag from parameter and call the notification api function also only one tag to see if it works. unfortunately still not able to work.

Comment: Before 

Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationOutcome outcome = null;

I did use GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0) to check , it has one  "username:test" tag